Нужно ли двоеточие или тире при таком перечислении?
Также мне интересны менеджмент, социология, политология и психология
или
В список моих интересов входят менеджмент, социология, политология и психология
После слова "интересы/интересов" нужно ли двоеточие или тире?
P.S. И правильно ли вообще говорить "интересов входят" или "интересов входит"?
